# Assigning a nested attribute with Formtastic

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, formtastic

I've been trying to figure this one out for a while but still no luck. I have a company_relationships table that joins **Companies** and **People**, storing an extra field to describe the nature of the relationship called 'corp_credit_id'. I can get the forms working fine to add company_relationships for a Person, but I can't seem to figure out how to set that modifier field when doing so. Any ideas?

More about my project: People have many companies through **company_relationships**. With that extra field in there I am using it to group all of the specific relationships together. So I can group a person's Doctors, Contractors, etc.

My models:

**Company.rb**  (abridged)

```
class Company < ActiveRecord::Base
   include ApplicationHelper

has_many :company_relationships
has_many :people, :through => :company_relationships
```

**Person.rb** (abridged)

```
class Person < ActiveRecord::Base
include ApplicationHelper

has_many :company_relationships
has_many :companies, :through => :company_relationships

accepts_nested_attributes_for :company_relationships
```

**company_relationship.rb**

```
class CompanyRelationship < ActiveRecord::Base
attr_accessible :company_id, :person_id, :corp_credits_id
belongs_to :company
belongs_to :person
belongs_to :corp_credits

end
```

My form partial, using formtastic.

```
<% semantic_form_for @person do |f| %>
<%= f.error_messages %>
<% f.inputs do %>
 ...
<%= f.input :companies, :as => :check_boxes, :label => "Favorite Coffee Shops", :label_method => :name,  :collection => Company.find(:all, :conditions => {:coffee_shop => 't'}, :order => "name ASC"), :required => false %>
```

So what I would like to do is something like :corp_credit_id => '1' in that input to assign that attribute for Coffee Shop. But formtastic doesn't appear to allow this assignment to happen.

Any ideas on how to do this?

Comment: Do you mean to say that when you create a company that is a coffee shop, the `corp_credit_id` column in the join table should be set to '1'?

Comment: No, I actually have booleans in the Company model to determine if it is in fact a coffee shop. What I'm trying to do is set the corp_credit_id when updating a Person, so I can assign all their Coffee Shops.

Answer (score 1):

Are you looking for something like

```
  <% semantic_form_for @person do |form| %>
    <% form.semantic_fields_for :company_relationships do |cr_f| %>
    <%= cr_f.input :corp_credit_id  %>
<% end %>
```

It is in the [documentation](http://github.com/justinfrench/formtastic)

Comment: I've tried that approach and I end up with it displaying several check_boxes, depending on how many existing company relationships there are.  What I would like to do is have one check_box or select box that allows for multiple selections. On submitting, it should update company_relationships and store a "1" in the corp_credit_id field in the case of coffee shops. (other numbers for other types of relationships).